Is a macOS System Call Tracing & Visualization Tool Useful?
I’m a beginner in reverse engineering and thinking of building a tool to trace and visualize system calls on macOS. The idea is to make something simpler than DTrace or Instruments, with an intuitive interface showing the sequence of system calls, parameters, and a graph view of interactions.
Before starting, I’d like to ask:
Would such a tool be useful for reverse engineering or malware analysis?
Are there easier or existing alternatives I might have missed?

Thanks for any feedback!

What did your research about existing tools reveal?

You might find it takes longer to write such a tool than learn to use what’s already there.
